# jquery .submit() function not work in ios

Tags: safari

I have bellow code:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function() {
    //Do something...
});
```

I have a form and when user press "Enter" key form should submit. It is working fine in all platforms but in ios safari not work. in the virtual keyboard of iphone there is a blue button as "Search" and when I click on it no reaction..!

Can any one help me?

Comment: You should wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {` ... `});` Can you try that? iOS may not initialized this function correctly.

Comment: Try submitting the form on click like: `$('#my-form input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){  $('#my-form').submit();  }):`

Comment: Wrapped in ready() @C0dekid

Comment: I try your solution, but not work @AfikDeri